# Fixing cell-spacing for corner cells for div[display:table]

Tags: css, grid-layout, css-tables

I am working on a `display: table`-based grid approach for my inner css framework and just faced a crucial problem with the whole thing. Basically, I want my layout to look like this:
[image]
Gray area here is supposed to be derived from `cell-spacing` attribute. Ideally, source would look like this, nothing new invented:

```
<div class="unit">
    <div class="one third"></div>
    <div class="two thirds"></div>
</div>
```

Here comes the problem I was talking about. In fact, `cell-spacing` is defined for all cells and wraps them with fixed margin. In my case, I don't want it to wrap corner cells at corresponding sides (for instance, so top-left cell does not produce spacing at top and left). First obvious solution that came to my mind is to use negative margin:

```
.unit {
    display: table;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;

    border-spacing: 0.2em;
    margin: -0.2em;
}
```

Unfortunely, this doesn't work as expected. It does remove top-left spacing, but leaves right one untoched. Any ideas on fixing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is good, but the problem is that the table is not wide enough. You can fix it with [`calc`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc):

```css
width: calc(100% + 2*0.2em);
```

Then, the table will be wider than its containing block. But that's not a big problem, because the cells will be positioned correctly because of the negative margins. You only need to add `overflow: hidden` to the container.

```css
.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.unit {
  display: table;
  overflow: auto;
  background: #aaa;
  border-spacing: 2em;
  margin: -2em;
  width: 100%; /* fallback */
  width: calc(100% + 2*2em);
}
.unit > * {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 2px solid;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="unit">
    <div class="one third">a</div>
    <div class="two thirds">b</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am afraid that this will issue a horizontal scroll bar for full-width containers, which I'd like to avoid :\

Comment: @IllyaKovalevskyy I forgot to say you need `overflow: hidden` on the container. See the demo, there is no scrollbar.

Comment: that's awesome! Danke-danke!

Comment: Not really the final thing. There is a regression for inner `.unit` blocks... Take a look: http://habrastorage.org/files/333/190/139/3331901398254b07830ff1889e0597a9.png

Comment: As you can see, inner blocks are being cut hard here :\

Comment: Never mind, I just forgot to set usual `width: 100%` for all inner blocks :)